# Why btn is blinking when mouse over?

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

What I want to do is: I want an image that has nothing. But when the user passes the mouse over I wan to display a button (I already got this). But I am having problem with my button because when I put the mouse over the button, it starts to blink and I do not know how stop this.

```js
function showBTN() {
    var x = document.getElementById('butt');
    x.style.display = 'block';
}

function removeBTN() {
    var y = document.getElementById('butt');
    y.style.display = 'none';
}
```

```css
.container {
    position: relative;
}

.container img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.container .btn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 12px 24px;
    text-align: center;
  }
```

```html
<h6 class="date">October 13, 2017</h6>

<h3>Contact Mgmt. - C</h3>

<div class="container p-0 m-0">

 <img
     src="https://picsum.photos/254/384?grayscale"
     style="border-radius: 10px;"
     onmouseover="showBTN()"
     onmouseout="removeBTN()"
 />

  <a
    id="butt"
    style="display: none;"
    href="https://github.com"
    class="btn btn-outline-success">
   Github code
  </a>

</div>
```

This is the Javascript that I am using to make the button appear 
and disappear when user moves the mouse over or move mouse out.
This functions are called into the a tag.

This is the code responsible for the css that I am using
Every time I put my mouse over the button it starts blinking, I am trying to stop it and make it act like normal.

Comment: When the mouse moves over the button it also moves *out* of the image triggering the `mouseout` handler, hiding the button. Then, and I assume the two elements are overlapping each other, the cursor is over the image again, so the `mouseover` handler is triggered, and so forth. It might be better to put the event handlers on the parent `div` of both of the elements.

Answer (score 1):

Why won't you do it with just CSS?

```css
.show-n-hide .btn-show-n-hide {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.show-n-hide:hover .btn-show-n-hide {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="show-n-hide">
  <span>Let's pretent that I'm the image. Hover over me.</span>

  <a id="butt" href="https://github.com" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-show-n-hide"> Github code
</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It blinks because when you hover over the button the `img`'s `mouseout` triggers. Putting the events on the `img` and button container solves it:

```js
function showBTN() {
    var x = document.getElementById('butt');
    x.style.display = 'block';
}

function removeBTN() {
    var y = document.getElementById('butt');
    y.style.display = 'none';
}
```

```css
.container {
    position: relative;
}

.container img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.container .btn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 12px 24px;
    text-align: center;
  }
```

```html
<h6 class="date">October 13, 2017</h6>

<h3>Contact Mgmt. - C</h3>

<div class="container p-0 m-0"
     onmouseover="showBTN()"
     onmouseout="removeBTN()">

 <img
     src="https://picsum.photos/254/384?grayscale"
     style="border-radius: 10px;"
 />

  <a
    id="butt"
    style="display: none;"
    href="https://github.com"
    class="btn btn-outline-success">
   Github code
  </a>

</div>
```